# How can I set value in select option using jQuery dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html-select

Below I am giving the snapshot of my code. Here I am facing the problem because in some dropdown value is set using below code but some dropdown is not getting set. Please tell me where am I going wrong.

```
function templateLoading(value){

    alert(value);

    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "templateload.ank?name="+value,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data) {

            alert(data);
            $.each(data,function(key, val) {
                //alert("fc"+"'"+key+"'");

                if(key=="fileHeaderAvailbale"){
                    alert(key +"fileHeaderAvailbale");



                }
```

// in key -->dynamically component id is coming and in the "value" value is coming which previous I set. I want to set all these previous value to related component by using id which is coming through key.

```
                    $("#"+key).val(val);


                //document.getElementById(key).value=val;

            });
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            //document.getElementById("FooterConstant").value= "rama";  
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);

        },
    })
}
```

My HTML code is below. This HTML code belong to problem page which is showing in image when you click the below link.

[Click here to see Screen shot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwpQn.png)

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>Header Details tab Configuration</legend>

            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="fheader">File Header Available: </label></td>
                    <td><select id="fileHeaderAvailbale" onchange="fileHeaderAvail(value);" name="fheader">
                             <option value="default">Select</option> 
                            <option value="YES">YES</option>
                            <option value="NO">NO</option>
                    </select></td>

                    <td><label for="dupHeader">Duplicate Check Header:</label></td>
                    <td><select id="duplicateCheckHeader" disabled="disabled" name="dupHeader">
                            <option value="default">Select</option>
                            <option value="YES">YES</option>
                            <option value="NO">NO</option>
                    </select></td>

                    <td><label for="mlHeader">MultiLine Header: </label></td>
                    <td><select id="multilineHeader"
                        onchange="multiLineHeaderAvail(value);" disabled="disabled" name="mlHeader">
                            <option value="default">Select</option>
                            <option value="YES">YES</option>
                            <option value="NO">NO</option>
                    </select></td>


                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for="headerType">Header Key Type:</label></td>
                    <td><select id="headerKeyType"
                        onchange="multipleHeaderDataCountSet(value);" disabled="disabled" name="headerType">
                            <option value="default">Select</option>
                            <option value="SingleHeaderKey">SingleHeaderKey</option>
                            <option value="MultipleHeaderKey">MultipleHeaderKey</option>
                    </select></td>

                    <td><label for="mheaderDataCount">Multiple Header
                            Data Count: </label></td>
                    <td><input id="multipleHeaderDataCount" name="mheaderDataCount"
                        type="text" class="required" disabled="disabled"></td>


                    <td><label for="lnkItem">Link Item changes to link</label></td>

                    <td><a href="#" id="lnkItem">Header Details</a></td>

                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td><label for="lineHeaderRecord">Line Between Header
                            and Data Record: </label></td>
                    <td><input id="lineBetweenHeaderData" name="lineHeaderRecord"
                        type="text" class="required"></td>

                    <td><label for="headerSequenceCheck">Header Sequence
                            Check Applicable: </label></td>
                    <td><select id="headerSequenceCheck" disabled="disabled"
                        onchange="hdrSeqChkApplicable(value);" name="headerSequenceCheck">
                            <option value="default">Select</option>
                            <option value="YES">YES</option>
                            <option value="NO">NO</option>
                    </select></td>

                    <td><label for=headerSequenceFormat> Header Sequence
                            Format: </label></td>
                    <td><input id="headerSequenceFormat"
                        name="headerSequenceFormat" type="text" class="required"
                        disabled="disabled"></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for="dataRecord">Data Record Between
                            Header:</label></td>
                    <td><input id="datarecordBetweenHeader" name="dataRecord" type="text"
                        disabled="disabled" class="required"></td>

                    <td><label for="headerAvail">Header Tag Available :</label></td>
                    <td><select id="headerTagAvailbale"
                        onchange="headerTagAvail(value);" disabled="disabled" name="headerAvail">
                            <option value="default">Select</option>
                            <option value="YES">YES</option>
                            <option value="NO">NO</option>
                    </select></td>

                    <td><label for=headerTagName> Header Tag Name: </label></td>
                    <td><input id="headertagName" name="headerTagName"
                        disabled="disabled" type="text" class="required"></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for=childTagCount> Header Child Tag Count:
                    </label></td>
                    <td><input id="headerChildTagCount" name="childTagCount"
                        disabled="disabled" type="text" class="required"></td>



                    <td><label for=dataElement>Header Data Element: </label></td>
                    <td><input id="headerdataElement" name="dataElement" type="text"
                        disabled="disabled" class="required"></td>

                </tr>

            </table>
        </fieldset>
```

And data is coming in JSON format like below.

```
    {
    "fileName": "IRIS",
    "sequenceNumber": 0,
    "constvalue": "12",
    "databeginCheck": "Yes",
    "databeginConst": "NO",
    "datarecordBetweenHeader": "13",
    "datarecordConst": "Yes",
    "datawithMulticonst": "50",
    "defineConst": "asd",
    "delimeter": ",",
    "duplicateCheck": "YES",
    "duplicateCheckHeader": "",
    "fileBeginWith": "IRIS2015",
    "fileBeginWithCheck": "YES",
    "fileHeaderAvailbale": "Yes",
    "fileId": 0,
    "fileLocation": "Local",
    "fileNameConvention": "DD:MM:yyyy",
    "fileNameConventionCheckApplicable": "NO",
    "fileNameLength": "15",
    "filePath": "D://IRIS/2015/ABC",
    "fileShortName": "IRIS125",
    "fileType": "Delimited",
    "filefooterAvailable": "YES",
    "filefooterWithConst": "YES",
    "footerConst": "asdfg",
    "footerFormat": "YYMMDDHHMI",
    "footerFormateCheck": "YYMMDDHHMI",
    "footerLength": "16",
    "footerType": "FixedLength",
    "headerChildTagCount": "No",
    "headerKeyType": "asce",
    "headerSequenceCheck": "No",
    "headerSequenceFormat": "3",
    "headerTagAvailbale": "12",
    "headerdataElement": "uihk",
    "headertagName": "Yes",
    "lineBetweenFooterData": "15",
    "lineBetweenHeaderData": "MultipleHeaderKey",
    "linebetweenDataRecord": "14",
    "multilineHeader": "No",
    "multilineRecordCheck": "NO",
    "multipleHeaderDataCount": "15",
    "noTagcontrol": "15",
    "numberConstant": "01",
    "numberLine": "41",
    "numberOfColumns": "10",
    "recordcountLine": "Yes",
    "selectResources": "null"
}
```

And my screen is below, I commented where the value is not getting set. Below I provide link of my image please click on this screen shot and tell me where I am going  wrong.

[Click here to see Screen shot of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwpQn.png)

Thanks & regards,
Shivam

Comment: Is it perhaps case-sensitive?  The values in the JSON and the values in the markup aren't exact.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code:

Values in dropdown are uppercase, thats why not selecting it.

```
$.each(data,function(key, val) {     
   var $dd = $("#"+key);
   if($dd && $dd.length > 0){
      console.log(key, val);
      $dd.val(val.toUpperCase());
   }
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/13749/

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
$('#headerSequenceCheck option:selected').val('No');
```